# I am learning HTML and CSS. I am trying to fit 9 images in one single horizontal line along with a text below the image but not able to do it

Tags: html, css

```
            <div class="sliderItem">
                <img src="./image/Accessories.png" width="130" height="80" alt="" class="sliderImg">
                <span class="caption">Accessories</span>
            </div>
```

I tried in CSS to align them but not getting the expected result.
It is showing images with text below but not on same line.

```
.sliderItem {
    vertical-align: horizontal;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.caption{
    display: block
}
```

Comment: Hi @Rutuja! The snippets of HTML & CSS you shared look fine. If I take your HTML & CSS, place them in a "containing" div, I get something like: https://codepen.io/jpattishall/pen/poxrEyy The containing div has a style to prevent "wrapping", which may or may not be a requirement for you. I added it so the effect is very apparent. Good luck learning HTML & CSS!

Comment: You can use display:flex and justify-content: space-between hopefully you will get the desired design

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align: horizontal` is an invalid property value. I couldn't get what are you expecting it to result.

Anyway consider the following code:
HTML:

```
<div class="sliderItem">
                <img src="./image/Accessories.png" width="130" height="80" alt="" class="sliderImg">
                <img src="2.png" width="130" height="80" alt="" class="sliderImg">
                <img src="3.png" width="130" height="80" alt="" class="sliderImg">
                <img src="4.png" width="130" height="80" alt="" class="sliderImg">
                <img src="5.png" width="130" height="80" alt="" class="sliderImg">
                <img src="6.png" width="130" height="80" alt="" class="sliderImg">
                <img src="7.png" width="130" height="80" alt="" class="sliderImg">
                <img src="8.png" width="130" height="80" alt="" class="sliderImg">
                <img src="9.png" width="130" height="80" alt="" class="sliderImg">
                <div class="caption">
                  <span>Accessories</span>
                  <span>2</span>
                  <span>3</span>
                  <span>4</span>
                  <span>5</span>
                  <span>6</span>
                  <span>7</span>
                  <span>8</span>
                  <span>9</span>
                </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sliderItem {
    display:inline-block;
}

.caption{
    width: 1170px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Hii, Next time you ask a question, please make sure to add all required information for someone to be able to answer. For example, in this case you could have added the `img src` code for all 9 images, so that others can answer better.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question sir and sorry for the insufficient information. Next time I'll take care of it.

Comment: @Rutuja your problem solved? Are you getting results as you wanted?

Comment: Here 1170 is 9 times 130

Answer (score 0):

There are different solutions. This is one:

```
<section id="wrapper">
    <div>
        <img src="test.png" alt="">
        <span>Accessories</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="test.png" alt="">
        <span>Accessories</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="test.png" alt="">
        <span>Accessories</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="test.png" alt="">
        <span>Accessories</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="test.png" alt="">
        <span>Accessories</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="test.png" alt="">
        <span>Accessories</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="test.png" alt="">
        <span>Accessories</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="test.png" alt="">
        <span>Accessories</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="test.png" alt="">
        <span>Accessories</span>
    </div>
</section>

#wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 5px;
}

#wrapper div {
    width: clamp(100px,100%,200px);
}

#wrapper div img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#wrapper span {
    font-size: 0.5em;
}
```